# Wait for RunOnUIThread to finish and continue executing the rest of the task

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

im developing an app for android via `c#(xamarin.visual studio)` , the problem is that i have some task to do that running in other threads , and when it should update the layout it should call `Activity.RunOnUIThread` , everything it's working well but the thread dont wait this method to finnish and continue executing the rest withuout waiting.

The question is : How to wait for `RunOnUIThread` to finish and after that continue executing rest of the commands of the task. ?

```
public void start(int threadCounter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCounter; i++)
        {

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunScanTcp));
            thread1.Start();

        }

    }
    public void RunScanTcp()
    {

        int port;

        //while there are more ports to scan 
        while ((port = portList.NextPort()) != -1)
        {
            count = port;

            Thread.Sleep(1000); //lets be a good citizen to the cpu

            Console.WriteLine("Current Port Count : " + count.ToString());

            try
            {

                Connect(host, port, tcpTimeout);

            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }

            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                mdata.Add(new data() { titulli = "Port : " + port, sekuenca = "Sequence : ", ttl = "Connection Sucessfull !", madhesia = "", koha = "Time : " });
                mAdapter.NotifyItemInserted(mdata.Count() - 1);
                if (ndaluar == false)
                {
                    mRecyclerView.ScrollToPosition(mdata.Count() - 1);
                }
            }); // in that point i want to wait this to finish and than continue below...
            Console.WriteLine("TCP Port {0} is open ", port);

        }
```

Comment: Please see my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should avoid creating new `Threads`.
In you case you must use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to enqueue the CPU bound operation.
Then you could use a `ManualResetEventSlim` or `TaskCompletionSource`  to synchronize the the `UI thread` and the Worker Thread.

Example:

```
// mre is used to block and release threads manually. It is
// created in the unsignaled state.

ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

RunOnUiThread(() =>
{            
    // Update UI here.
    // Release Manual reset event.

    mre.Set();
});

// Wait until UI operations end.
mre.Wait();
```

---

In your specific case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadCounter; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunScanTcp);
}

private void RunScanTcp(object stateInfo) 
{
    // Do CPU bound operation here.
    var a = 100;
    while (--a != 0)
    {
        // mre is used to block and release threads manually. It is
        // created in the unsignaled state.
        ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            // Update UI here.

            // Release Manual reset event.
            mre.Set();
        });

        // Wait until UI operation ends.
        mre.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

If you prefer to use `TaskCompletionSource` you could use an **alternative approach**:

```
private async void RunScanTcp(object stateInfo)
{
    // Do CPU bound operation here.
    var a = 100;
    while (--a != 0)
    {
        // using TaskCompletionSource
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            // Update UI here.

            // Set result
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        });

        // Wait until UI operationds.
        tcs.Task.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: So , it's better to use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` than creating new threads ? i will try this solution , thanks

Comment: Yes is better because ThreadPool is managed by the Runtime. I could replace your code with the one I gave you, it will run out of the box, I tested on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` with a shared `myLock` object to wait for the UI execution.

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    mdata.Add(new data() { titulli = "Port : " + port, sekuenca = "Sequence : ", ttl = "Connection Sucessfull !", madhesia = "", koha = "Time : " });
    mAdapter.NotifyItemInserted(mdata.Count() - 1);
    if (ndaluar == false)
    {
        mRecyclerView.ScrollToPosition(mdata.Count() - 1);
    }
    lock(myLock) Monitor.Pulse(myLock)
});
lock(myLock) Monitor.Wait(myLock)
Console.WriteLine("TCP Port {0} is open ", port);
```

Comment: `myLock` could be any object within the right scope.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in an `async`/`await` solution, there is Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncManualResetEvent`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncManualResetEvent), e.g.:

```
var mre = new AsyncManualResetEvent();
this.context.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    // Do awesome UI stuff
    mre.Set();
});
await mre.WaitAsync();
```